# Delphi - Conexao tcp com protocolo CSTA?

Tags: delphi-xe6

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
Var
   Result: string;
   Tamanho: Integer;
  I, Cont, D: Integer;
begin
   Edit3.Text:= '';
   Cont:= 0;
   Tamanho:= Length(Edit1.Text);
   D:= Tamanho;
   while Cont <= D do
   Begin

     Edit2.Text:= copy(Edit1.Text, Cont, 3);
     IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.WriteLn (Edit2.Text);
     if Cont < 3 then
        Edit3.Text:= Edit3.Text + copy(Edit1.Text, Cont, 2)
     else
        Edit3.Text:= Edit3.Text + copy(Edit1.Text, Cont, 3);
     //ShowMessage(IntToStr(Cont));
     Cont:= Cont + 3;
   End;
   Result := idTCPClient1.LastCmdResult.ToString;
   Label1.Caption:= Result + '  ' + IntToStr (Tamanho);
end;
```

Comment: Explique melhor sua dúvida/problema.

Comment: Alguém conhece este protocolo, e algum exemplo de conexão usando o delphi? No procedimento acima, consigo conectar no equipamento que rola o protocolo mas não consigo autenticar! Informação que o fabricante do equipamento dispoe:

Comment: 4.3.  Autenticação Para que o cliente possa receber e enviar dados CSTA, é necessário o envio de uma mensagem de autenticação. A autenticação é feita utilizando o protocolo ACSE, onde são passados o id da aplicação, o usuário e a senha. Formato ACSE Utiliza-se o padrão ACSE – 1 definido na norma X.227:04/1995. Tipos de pacotes ACSE » AARQ : Solicitação de conexão. Enviado pelo cliente. » AARE : resposta do AARQ. Enviado pelo servidor » RLRQ : Solicitação de desconexão. Enviado pelo cliente »

Comment: RLRE : Resposta de RLRQ. Enviado pelo servidor » ABRT: Finalização forçada da conexão. Enviado pelo servidor ou pelo cliente. Não necessita de resposta.